# preproccessing image data from csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, computer-vision

In my dataframe I have one pixel column which has row vector of images in each row.
like this:

```
              pixels
        0     70 66 34 56 23 45 8 5 34... 
        1     79 63 54 96 83 57 8 5 34...
```

I want to make column of each element in row vector.
like this:

```
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
        0     70 66 34 56 23 45 81 52 34... 
        1     79 63 54 96 83 57 81 53 34...
```

Comment: it seems you need `df.pixels.str.split()`

Comment: it is dupe :( 
I think

Comment: it giving error:'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pixels'

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: [0,1,2,3,4,5,.....199] it is index i think

Comment: So there is no `pixels` column?

Comment: giving ..['pixels']

Comment: So maybe need `df1 = df['pixels'].str.split()`

Comment: gives:
KeyError: 'pixels'

Comment: OK, what is `print (df.head().to_dict())` of first DataFrame?

Comment: after some change:   df1 = df['pixels'].str.split()         like this                                     0    [70, 80, 82, 72, 58, 58, 60, 63, 54, 58, 60, 4...
1    [151, 150, 147, 155, 148, 133, 111, 140, 170, ...
2    [231, 212, 156, 164, 174, 138, 161, 173, 182, ...